# Set textbox height fixed, if no value in access reports

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to fix the `text box` height in Microsoft Access `Report`. Even if there is no data or `null` in that `text box`, it will still be fixed. How can I do it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Set its _CanShrink_ property to False.

Comment: Fantastic!! Thanks a lot.